# add users from database to json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, flask

I have a database with users. This is the [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVU4z.jpg).

My question is: **how to create `json` file, so I can see all users in `json-format` like that**:

```
{
    "id": "47",
    "firstname": "user",
    "lastname": "user",
    "email": "uuser@example.com",
    "born_date": "17.06.2020",
    "password": "123123",
    "phone_number": "123123123",
    "description": "firstdescription"
},
```

So, **I need to add exist users from db to `json-format` to new created `json file` and add every new-registered user to my json file**

`User registration code:`

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.form['firstname']
        lastname = request.form['lastname']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        phone_number = request.form['number']
        born_date = request.form['date']
        description = request.form['description']

        # password = hashlib.md5(password.encode())
        # password = password.hexdigest()

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users.data WHERE email = %s AND password = %s',
                    (email, password))

        account = cur.fetchone() # get all in account variable

        if account:
            return render_template('exist.html')
        else:
            session['email'] = email
            session['firstname'] = firstname
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO users.data(firstname, lastname, email, born_date, password, phone_number, description) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',
                                                (firstname, lastname, email, born_date, password, phone_number, description))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            cur.close()
            return redirect(url_for('profile'))

    return render_template('register.html')
```

Comment: It looks like you have already done it, what is the problem here ?

Comment: @Sushanth, I wrote it manually. I need to do it for all users.

Comment: @Sushanth, could you please help me with this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by this way:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.form['firstname']
        lastname = request.form['lastname']
        email = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['password']
        phone_number = request.form['number']
        born_date = request.form['date']
        description = request.form['description']

        # password = hashlib.md5(password.encode())
        # password = password.hexdigest()

        cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users.data WHERE email = %s AND password = %s',
                    (email, password))

        account = cur.fetchone() # get all in account variable

        if account:
            return render_template('exist.html')
        else:
            session['email'] = email
            session['firstname'] = firstname
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO users.data(firstname, lastname, email, born_date, password, phone_number, description) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',
                                                (firstname, lastname, email, born_date, password, phone_number, description))
            mysql.connection.commit()
            cur.close()

            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT id, firstname, lastname, email, born_date, password, phone_number FROM users.data WHERE description = 'doctor'") # тут добавить выбор id, born_date, password, phone_number
            account = cur.fetchall()
            description = account
            cur.close()

            cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
            cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users.data")
            account = cur.fetchall()
            description = account
            content = {}
            content = description
            with open('data_json.json', 'w') as json_file:
                json.dump(content, json_file, indent=4)

            return render_template('profile.html', email=session['email'], firstname=session['firstname'], description=description)
return render_template('register.html')
```